# Are tags like asp:xxx the best way to implement data in an ASP.NETapplication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have to redesign a website built with ASP.NET.

I'm not really comfortable with this technology, and I have a hard time implementing Boostrap's classes on ASP tags such as

```
<asp:Localize ID="lblCompanyCountry" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblCompanyCountry" Text="Your company is based in: "></asp:Localize>
```

Or

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lsbCompanyCountry" runat="server" Height="20px"    Width="326px" meta:resourcekey="lsbCompanyCountry">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

I'm aware that I can use CssClass to attribute a Bootstrap Class to a tag. But unfortunately, it's never working properly.

---

I did some research and found out that the most common way to transmit data to the view is with this kind of instructions :

```
@{
  if (IsPost) { 
    string companyname = Request["CompanyName"]; 
    string contactname = Request["ContactName"]; 
    <p>
      You entered: <br />
      Company Name: @companyname <br />
      Contact Name: @contactname
    </p>
  }
```

So I'm wondering if I'm dealing with a some kind of "old" ASP.NET, or if I'm missing something.

Comment: You are dealing with classic ASP.Net Web Forms. Do you have a choice in how you solve the problem?  Moving to ASP.Net MVC could be a huge improvement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry my late one.
The client I'm working for doesn't want to change the back-end of the application, so I can't move to ASP.Net MVC.
So I have to use only CSS to redesign the application, right ?

Comment: Yes, you will have to inject CSS and/or JavaScript into the pages.  It's been a while since I had to use webforms, but I'll see what I can dig up.  You can search on ASP.Net Webforms client script - should turn up more information on how to work with it.

Comment: That's what I thought, I'll go with CSS and JavaScript. I'll search what you suggested, thank you a lot !